# HTML, CSS Image grid (responsive)

Tags: jquery, html, css, grid

i tried to realize the following grid: http://abload.de/img/raster0qe3g.jpg

the images should keep their aspect ratio in percent and the space between them should be 20px

i added `box-sizing:border-box;` to the li and `width:100%; / width:50%;`

JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/t9c7N/2/

i have tried a lot of things but there are always some mystic spaces

can anyone help me ?

greets

Comment: Open your browser's dev tools to see which padding/border/margin to remove. I think it's related to box model, as lists have padding+margin automatically set.

Comment: already did - found nothing, percent is not working correctly

Comment: Which of the spaces do you mean with the mystic spaces? The only problem I can see is with lack of space in some places (where the images are stuck together with nothing in between).

Comment: the images did not fix correctly - now i realized this with https://github.com/kombai/freewall (works perfect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

done with:
https://github.com/kombai/freewall

works perfect for that grid